# How long is the SHA256 hash?

Tags: mysql, sha256

I'm going to run `SHA256` on a password + salt, but I don't know how long to make my `VARCHAR` when setting up the MySQL database. What is a good length?

Comment: Before anyone reading this decides to follow this advice and use `SHA-*` to hash passwords, [PLEASE read this first](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16354/whats-the-advantage-of-using-pbkdf2-vs-sha256-to-generate-an-aes-encryption-key).

Comment: Unless you’re using SHA-256 on passwords, which you shouldn’t do, the hashes have a length of 256 bits, or 64 hexadecimal characters, or 43 alphanumeric characters, or 32 bytes.

Comment: @c00000fd: I'm not sure that the link is particularly relevant. The OP specifically wants to use a 'password+salt'. If the salt is 16 random characters, for example, then it doesn't matter that SHA-256 is 'fast', and dictionary attacks are then impossible. See the gnu docs for `crypt` for example code. SHA-x is fine for passphrases, as long as you know what you're doing.

Comment: @EML: That link is the correct one for this, and it absolutely does matter that SHA-256 is fast. SHA-x is bad for passphrases, even if you know what you're doing.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: do the sums. If SHA-x must be run `n` times to break a plain password, then adding a 16-byte salt means that it has to be run `n * 256^16` times instead. Even if the password itself was trivially short - say one printable character - then SHA-x must be run `3 * 10^40` times to test all possibilities. If you've got a GPU setup that runs at 11 billion SHA-256 ops/second, this is `3 * 10^30` seconds. This is *vastly* longer than the age of the universe. Ergo, the fact that SHA-x is "fast" is utterly irrelevant.

Comment: @EML: You are completely misunderstanding the function of the salt. The salt is not a secret.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: the salt is recorded only in the *hash output*, or equivalently, and *is* a secret, unless the attacker has access to the hashes (in `/etc/shadow`, or wherever). If they have that access, it's game over anyway. If the salt wasn't a secret it would be completely pointless.

Comment: @EML: Stop already, you don't know what you're talking about. Do some research.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: if you have a point to make, explain why the calculation is incorrect, rather than just explaining how clever you are or how stupid I am.

Comment: @EML: The salt *is* intended to guard against cases where the attacker steals copies of the password hashes, e.g. from `/etc/shadow`, as the salts are stored with the hashes. Without the salt, it's susceptible to (e.g.) rainbow table attacks, where the hash is precomputed, so the hash function cost doesn't matter. With a sizeable salt, the number of precomputed hashes becomes prohibitively huge. If computing hashes on-demand, however, then the salt doesn't help—if the attacker has the hashes, they also have salts. At this point the cost of the hash function now becomes important.

Answer (score 450, accepted):

A sha256 is 256 bits long -- as its name indicates.

Since sha256 returns a hexadecimal representation, 4 bits are enough to encode each character (instead of 8, like for ASCII), so 256 bits would represent 64 hex characters, therefore you need a `varchar(64)`, or even a `char(64)`, as the length is always the same, not varying at all.

And the demo :

```
$hash = hash('sha256', 'hello, world!');
var_dump($hash);
```

Will give you :

```
$ php temp.php
string(64) "68e656b251e67e8358bef8483ab0d51c6619f3e7a1a9f0e75838d41ff368f728"
```

i.e. a string with 64 characters.

Comment: can we use char(64) as the primary key or will binary(32) be better for that? (access_token)

Comment: If you think you might want to block a user in the future, then I suggest using `varchar(65)` for a leading `!`... just saying.

Comment: ...or just add a column 'blocked' ?

Comment: As you want to have a different salt for each password you have to store this next to the hash. For this you can use an extra field or pre-/append it to the hash, so you will need more than 64 chars

Comment: you can use this select statement to test it: `SELECT length(to_base64(unhex(sha2('say hello to my little friend',256))))` , it is always 44 whatever the length of original string is.

Comment: If you must use text, base64 encode to save some space, or better yet use a binary field

Comment: PLEASE DON'T JUST SHA-256 A PASSWORD w/ or w/o SALT.  Use PBKDF2, bcrypt, or scrypt.  If your password database is ever leaked, these are resistant to brute-force reversing.  https://medium.com/@kasunpdh/how-to-store-passwords-securely-with-pbkdf2-204487f14e84

Comment: @PatrickCornelissen: add the random salt to the *clear* passphrase, hash the *result*, and you still get 256 bits.

Comment: @EML and if you don't store the salt to apply it to the given phrase you want to match with the hash, how would you do that? Having a hash from something with a random salt you don't know anymore is just a random block of bits you dan't do anything useful with.

Comment: @PatrickCornelissen - Ok, that was unclear - I use the Posix/libc `cypt`, and the `crypt` output actually includes the hash, so can be used directly for testing. But the output is more than 256 bits, so, basically, exactly what you said... :)

Answer (score 86):

Encoding options for SHA256's 256 bits:

1. Base64: 6 bits per char = `CHAR(44)` including padding character
2. Hex: 4 bits per char = `CHAR(64)`
3. Binary: 8 bits per byte = `BINARY(32)`

Comment: Base64 is 3 bytes per 4 chars, so even though 32 bytes fits into 43 characters, you actually need 44. An extra = is added as the final character

Comment: Well, the `=` can be stripped and re-added.

Answer (score 36):

I prefer to use BINARY(32) since it's the optimized way!

You can place in that 32 hex digits from (00 to FF).

Therefore BINARY(32)!

Comment: +1 - I like optimized...to anyone else happening on this...to use this with MySQL...you can use `UPDATE...SET hash_column=UNHEX(sha256HexString)`. Then, when retrieving it, you `SELECT HEX(hash_column) AS hash_column`.

Comment: A pertinent MySQL doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html

Answer (score 26):

Why would you make it VARCHAR? It doesn't vary. It's always 64 characters, which can be determined by running anything into [one of the online SHA-256 calculators](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator).

Comment: is char(64) a valid mysql statement?

Comment: @hatorade: No it's not a statement, but it is a valid column type.

Comment: varchar also doesn’t allocate space unless its used, unlike char it allocates the number of amount of total characters allowed regardless if there is data filling it.

Answer (score 8):

It will be fixed 64 chars, so use `char(64)`

Comment: And use `CHARACTER SET ascii`.

Comment: Or [BINARY(64)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/binary/)as you not really dealing with text here.